# How to check if an object is an instance of given class, if this class is generic?

Tags: swift, generics, casting

How to check if an object is an instance of given class, if this class is generic ?

```
class DataSource<ItemType> {
}

[...]
func Test() {
    [...]
    let result = dataSource?.isKind(of: DataSource)
    print(result)
}
```

I obtain this error message : Generic parameter 'ItemType' could not be inferred

The same code in objective C (fully functional) :

```
@interface DataSource <ItemType : id> : NSObject
@implementation DataSource

if ([dataSource isKindOfClass:[DataSource class]]) { 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You kinda need to provide the generic, as `DataSource` without the generic argument is an incomplete type.

Comment: Why would  you need this, BTW?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, you can't.
Swift won't let you call a function with an incomplete type, as it can't generate code (at the machine level) for it.

Depending on your needs, you could create a protocol that provides a discriminant for your different cases, and make your `DataSource` conform to it:

```
enum Discriminant {
  case dataSource, notDataSource
}

protocol Discriminable {
  static var discriminant: Discriminant { get }
}

extension DataSource: Discriminable {
  static var discriminant: Discriminant { return .dataSource }
}

// ...

let result = type(of: dataSource).discriminant == .dataSource
print(result) // Prints "true"
```